# R: Lookup and sum millions of records, then find best one

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I have two data tables

This data table, dt1, shows the number of sales across each month for the last N years.

```
    Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec
 1:  35  46  37  14  13   6  38  25  12  42  10  43
 2:   3  36  20  32  18  48  42  27  38  48  15  34
 3:  11  40  49  19  50   5   9  38   8  12  45  40
```

Each employee has to guess 3 months. dt2 represents those guesses

```
    Guess1 Guess2 Guess3
 1:    Nov    Aug    Oct
 2:    Oct    Jan    Jul
 3:    Sep    May    Jun
```

What I want to do is find the sum of every guess for every year and increment a score for whichever combination ranks the highest. The data set I'm working with has millions of records in both data tables so I'm looking for a really efficient way to do this.

```
set.seed(1)
dt1 = as.data.table(replicate(12,sample(1:50,replace=F)))
setnames(dt1, month.abb)
set.seed(1)
dt2 = data.table(Guess1=sample(month.abb, 10), Guess2=sample(month.abb, 10), Guess3=sample(month.abb, 10))
dt2[, `:=` (Total = 0, Score = 0)]
for (i in 1:nrow(dt1)){
  thisRowAnswer = dt1[i]
  
  for(j in 1:nrow(dt2)){
    thisGuess1 = dt2[j, Guess1]
    thisGuess2 = dt2[j, Guess2]
    thisGuess3 = dt2[j, Guess3]
    # thisRowAnswer[, ..thisGuess1] works but thisRowAnswer[, ..dt2[j, Guess1]] does not
    dt2[j, "Total"] = thisRowAnswer[, ..thisGuess1][[1]] +  thisRowAnswer[, ..thisGuess2][[1]] +  thisRowAnswer[, ..thisGuess3][[1]]
  }
  
  maxTotal = max(dt2$Total)
  # Increment score for the highest total
  dt2[Total == maxTotal, Score := Score + 1]
}

# The winner is the person with the highest Score
```

Comment: You have deleted your original simlar question which I am solving :sad:

Comment: You should set `seed` for `sample` to reproduce it.

Comment: Updated to set the seed (I think I did that right). Also, yes sorry, I deleted it because I didn't think it was clear enough! Thought this example might be better

Comment: `dt2[, "Total"]` updates  for different row of `dt1`( I know it's important to calculate `Score`). Do you only want to keep its value for the last row of `dt1`?

Comment: `dt2[, "Total"]` is only used as a helper column for calculating the score. It just so happens that it's value is from the last row of `dt1`, but doesn't have to be.

Comment: What's the  row size of `dt2` in your real data?  If it is small, I can give one acceptable solution.

Comment: Dt2 has 1 million records and dt1 has 200k. My current solution takes 1 hour so anything less is still good!

Comment: You can test how much time  it spend for your real data. I'm happy to head that.

Comment: I don't understand your expected output, *"increment a score"*. If I understand correctly, for each row in `dt2`, we extract those months' columns from `dt1` and sum them; once that is done for all rows in `dt1`, we find the row with the max sum and then assign that `dt1`-row-number to `dt2`. Is that right?

Comment: @r2evans `Score` is a counter that is keeping track of the number of times that row had the highest total. So the correction to your last sentence: we find the row with the max sum and then _increment their `Score` column_. What I want to do is answer the question, which 3 guesses in dt2 had the highest Total across the entire dt1?

Answer (score 1):

This should be more efficient but may cost memory when `dt2` is large.

```
set.seed(1)
dt1 = as.data.table(replicate(12,sample(1:50,replace=F)))
setnames(dt1, month.abb)
dt2 = data.table(Guess1=sample(month.abb, 10), Guess2=sample(month.abb, 10), Guess3=sample(month.abb, 10))

for (i in 1:nrow(dt2)) {
    dt1[,paste0("sum_row_",i):=.SD[,as.vector(unlist(dt2[i,1:3])),with=FALSE][,rowSums(.SD)]]    
}

dt2[,Total:= as.numeric(unlist(dt1[.N,13:(13 + nrow(dt2) - 1)]))]

dt1[,Max := max.col(.SD),.SDcols=13:(13 + nrow(dt2) - 1)]
dt2[,Score:=as.vector(table(dt1[,Max]))]

% recover df1
% dt1[, (paste0("sum_row_",1:nrow(dt2))) := NULL]
```